# Proof that the Krull dimension of a ring R equals the dimension of Spec(R)

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

I need to prove that the Krull dimension of a ring $R$ equals the dimension of the Spectrum. I started by showing that in $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ the closed irreducible sets are the prime ideals and then the length of every chain $C$ in spectrum will be equal to the supremum of the length of prime chains. Is this enough? I can definitely understand why it stands but I’m not sure this is enough for a proof… I read something about geometric interpretation, is it maybe proven geometrically?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You're using a particular order-preserving bijection which you may want to state, but it can sometimes go without saying. Also, make sure to format your questions with mathjax for the best response. I edited this one for you.

Comment: If people give a less than best
 "best reposnes" because someone did not wrap in dollar signs a couple of capital letters, the problem is not really with the poster...

Comment: Thank you very much for the editing and the answer I’ll know from now on…